# SUM and SUBTRACT if criteria is matched on the same formula on Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I would like some help on how to SUM numbers of a column only if some criteria is matched and SUBTRACT from the first SUM only if some other criteria is matched?

Looking at the screenshot below. Iam basically looking for a formula to give me the balance for each metal.

[image]

Comment: I think that you need develop more this question, making an example or explain more are ways to improve this question

Comment: I wish I could. I cannot seem to edit my own question thus I cannot elaborate it more. I prepared a screenshot but can't edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
= QUERY(A1:C12,"Select A,sum(B)-sum(C) group by A",1)
```

Comment: I don't think this is working.
sum(B) is adding everything in B column independently os the metal thus giving me the result of everything all together and not separate.

Answer (score 1):

lets create a D column that have the result of the bought minus the sold

then in gold balance formula it can be something link this

=SUMIF(A2:A12,"GOLD","D2:D12")

Silver balance would be something like this

=SUMIF(A2:A12,"SILVER","D2:D12")

and at last bronze

=SUMIF(A2:A12,"BRONZE","D2:D12")

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you should be inserting;

GOLD BALANCE: =SUMIF(A2:A12, "GOLD", B2:B12) - SUMIF(A2:A12, "GOLD", C2:C12)

SILVER BALANCE: =SUMIF(A2:A12, "SILVER", B2:B12) - SUMIF(A2:A12, "SILVER", C2:C12)

BRONZE BALANCE: =SUMIF(A2:A12, "BRONZE", B2:B12) - SUMIF(A2:A12, "BRONZE", C2:C12)